# web request failures in curl

Tags: macos, network, command-line, ssl

I have a macbook pro running Catalina 10.15.1. However this issue has been present since at least Mojave.

After a reboot it runs fine for a while (up to about an hour but I haven't measured) and then most web requests start to fail. This does not affect Chrome which is my main browser, but for example running:

```
curl https://github.com
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

Running:

```
curl http://example.com
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`
```

A restart will fix both these issues temporarily.

I've tried using brew to update `curl` and `libressl` but they're both up to date.

```
curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) libcurl/7.64.1 (SecureTransport) 
LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.39.2
```

How do I fix these connection issues?

Comment: What is the version of curl you have now?

Comment: @Udhy version string is "curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) libcurl/7.64.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.39.2"

Comment: Try "networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi" without quote from the terminal and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: @Udhy Thanks, that didn't work even with sudo. Does it require a restart?

Comment: networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi - > works for me from the terminal and you should reboot to check it.

Comment: @Udhy I *think* that's worked, however it's hard to be sure because the issue only ever presented itself after the system had been running for at least an hour. Regardless if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer. It would be great if you can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two options that you can try;

First, try to run this command

```
export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1
```

And second, run the following command from your terminal:

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

Reboot the machine and check it.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of network or connection issues.

You have to find out where the issue is coming from.

- First try connecting through a mobile or a 4G connection to see if the issue is in your machine or the local network.
- If the issue is with the machine, try disabling firewalls, Anti-virus programs etc to find the root of problem.
- It can happen because of an incorrect IP v6 configuration. Try disabling IPv6 locally.
- Go to `System Preferences` > `Network`  > `TCP/IP` > Change `Configure IPv6` to `Link-local only`.
- If you have access to the router, try disabling IPv6 network. If that solves the issue, then there's a misconfiguration on router.
- After you found the cause, fix it and enable firewalls and anti-virus programs.